# The must-read User Interface Book?

Tags: resources, learning

I'm looking for *the* Book that explains the essentials of user interface and user experience design.

I read [Beautiful Visualization](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920000617) and [Designing Interfaces](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596008031) from O'Reilly. I think they are very good but, I'm still looking for *the one*.

**Please provide your recommendation and why it stands as the essential reference.**

Comment: "List of..." questions that can't have one, correct (for the asker) answer aren't really what Stack Exchange is about. A certain number have been tolerated on other sites, but you should really try to avoid asking them. However, I can see value in this one.

Comment: Strangely enough, these 'must read books' questions are pretty much my favourite part of every stackexchange site

Comment: Hello, the OP means to say "the one", the definitive one, **along with** the "Why" of it. Each reader can have his own "the one", with his own reasons. So, no "list of..." as such.

Comment: I am surprised that "Designing Web Usability" by Jakob Nielsen was not been included on the answers list. It is very pleasant to read and along with Steve Krug's "Don't Make Me Think", they are the only two usability books I've read from end-to-end.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

[Don't Make Me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789723107) by Steve Krug. The book is written in the way it preaches: very simple and easy to understand. The book covers a wide range of user experience topics. It's a must-read.

A new edition of this book as been released in early January 2014.  [Don't Make Me Think Revisited](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321965515)

Comment: I knew that someone else would beat me to naming this book. It's true though. Don't Make Me Think is the must read when you want to learn about design and usability.

Comment: Even if you are not a web developer this book is worth the effort. Very well written and insightful.

Comment: Agreed - it is one of the best books on the topic I know of, and a very easy read.

Comment: _Everyone_ recommends this one, but I'm hesitant because it's "A guide to _web_ usability" -- is it as applicable to desktop development, or development for a platform with a different usage model e.g. Silverlight?

Comment: @Robert - While it is a book about web usability, it does contain many lessons/concepts that are applicable to anything from a Silverlight app to the dashboard on your car. Just common sense ideas about how people's brains work and how they interact with things they see. That said, if you have absolutely zero interest in web or application UIs it might not be up your alley.

Comment: One of the best I've read. He makes you not only think but enjoy the book.

Comment: FWIW I find this book a dumbed down rehash of "The Inmates Are Running The Asylum" by Alan Cooper

Answer (score 148):

Don't forget the classic: [Don Norman's *The Design of Everyday Things*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E257T6C). Even though it is explicitly NOT about either web pages or computer applications, but about everyday things, there is so much there about common sense thinking about how people actually interact with things that I class it as a must-read.

Comment: And his later books, where he changes his mind on some things.

Comment: This is one of the books I had to read for one of my HCI courses.  Highly recommended

Comment: I agree. I liked the first half of the book better, but it's still a really good and revelatory read. I actually re-read a couple of months ago and realized that it hasn't lost any of its value.

Comment: Yup, everything in this book is spot-on until he starts talking about computers... I guess it was written before people actually *tied* voice interfaces.

Comment: Great book. It excited me about learning more about UX.

Comment: This is a great book and it breaks your brain. You can no longer look at common objects the same way, and your spouse will be angry with you for incessantly saying things like, "Why do I have to pour the contents of this thing out to find out that it contains salt? Would it have killed them to put a little 'S' on the outside?"

Comment: Anyone bought a cooking hob with Natural Mapping yet?

Comment: Love love love this book. It seems like a lot of interface designers have never read it.

Comment: Heads up - there's an [revised edition](http://www.jnd.org/books/design-of-everyday-things-revised.html) from 2013, which should fix some of the qualms mentioned in the comments. At least the examples feel up to date (including things like Nest, smartphones, etc.).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline what are some of the things Norman changes his opinion of?

Answer (score 67):

[Universal Principles of Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592535879)

Brilliant design book, especially useful for interface design.

Comment: This book was an optional book for my software usability course. Let's just say that of the two books, this is the one I kept. I would recommend it.

Comment: This is a great reference book that's easy to understand.

Comment: Agree, I have this one in my library and reference it so much. Lot's of valuable info in there.

Comment: beautiful book. how did i not spot it before. so useful and exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 54):

- [Designing Interfaces: Patterns for
  Effective Interaction Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596008031) by
  Jenifer Tidwell
- [About Face](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470084111) by Alan Cooper
- [The Smashing Book](https://shop.smashingmagazine.com/smashing-book-intl.html) by Smashing Magazine

Currently reading About Face. Really thorough and goes back to the basics of UI design.

Edit: Oops, just read you already read the first, but I leave it to be included if this turns into a full list of books.

Comment: About face is excellent, it covers do's and don'ts of interactive design but much more importantly teaches you to think about whether you actually need the interaction. 

There is no point in designing a really usable interaction for the sake of it. Its much better to try and make your system clever enough to make the interaction obsolete.

Answer (score 48):

[The Visual Display of Quantitative Information](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/096139210X) by Edward R Tufte is extremely useful for training your eyes to filter non-essential design elements and focus on the essence of the information.

Comment: The other Tufte books are worth reading as well - actually, don't just read them - study them.

Comment: "...and focus on the essence of the information." Then, hopefully, it inspires you to go back, identify the elements that were "non-essential," and remove them.

Comment: "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away"

Answer (score 32):

I'd be remiss not to mention [Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/)'s [User Interface Design for Programmers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1893115941). There's an [online version](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html) but the printed book has about 50% more material.

Comment: This is my prefered 'Read This First' suggestion. It contains the two great nuggets of wisdom:  1 - Users Don't Read the Manual.  2 - In fact, users don't read anything...

Answer (score 30):

- [Don't Make Me Think](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0789723107) by Steve
  Krug.
- [The Non-Designer's Design Book:
  Design and Typographic Principles for
  the Visual Novice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1566091594) by Robin
  Williams.

Also, while these aren't books, you may benefit from browsing some design pattern libraries. Each of these shows common patterns and explains when they are appropriate to use.

- [Yahoo's Design Pattern Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/)
- [Welie.com's Pattern Library](http://www.welie.com/patterns/)
- [UIPatterns](http://ui-patterns.com/)

Comment: The Krug book is covered in a separate entry - would you mind editing it out?

Comment: The UIPatterns website is companion to Jennifer Tidwell's Designing Interfaces I believe.

Answer (score 29):

If you're interested specifically in forms, I can recommend [Web Form Design: Filling in the Blanks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933820241)  by Luke Wroblewski.

Comment: I just finished this book. It was VERY worth my time.

Comment: Happy to hear it :)

Answer (score 27):

[The Humane Interface: New Directions for Designing Interactive Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201379376) by Jef Raskin

From the back cover:

> This unique guide to interactive
>   system design reflects the experience
>   and vision of Jef Raskin, the creator
>   of the Apple Macintosh. Other books
>   may show how to use today's widgets
>   and interface ideas effectively.
>   Raskin, however, demonstrates that
>   many current interface paradigms are
>   dead ends, and that to make computers
>   significantly easier to use requires
>   new approaches. He explains how to
>   effect desperately needed changes,
>   offering a wealth of innovative and
>   specific interface ideas for software
>   designers, developers, and product
>   managers.

Answer (score 20):

Some favorites:

- Designing Web Interfaces by Bill Scott
- The Inmates Are Running The Asylum by Alan Cooper
- Envisioning Information by Edward Tufte (really any Tufte book)
- Designing the Obvious by Robert Hoekman
- Defensive Design by 37 Signals

---

- The Humane Interface by Jef Raskin
- The Design of Everyday Things by Donald Norman
- Don't Make Me Think by Steve Krug
- About Face by Alan Cooper
- Web Form Design: Filling in the Blanks by Luke Wroblewski

Each of these books has taught me something new or given insight into how to do things better.

Top half not recommended by above posts.

Comment: Jason, mind breaking out the entries in this list that aren't otherwise represented? Would be helpful to be able to vote up-down on the merit of individual entries -- the collection of works in the list aren't all tied for 1st, and some already exist as individual posts.

Answer (score 15):

Surprised that Krug's [Rocket Surgery Made Easy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321657292) has not been mentioned, given that *Don't Make Me Think* is so widely praised. RSME is just as good and useful in UI design.

An excerpt from the back cover: *In this new book, Steve explains how to* -

- *Test any design, from a sketch on a napkin to a fully-functioning web site or application*
- *Keep your focus on finding the most important problems (because no one has the time or resources to fix them all)*
- *Fix the problems that you find, using his "The least you can do" approach*

Answer (score 14):

I'm really surprised that [GUI Bloopers 2.0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123706432) hasn't been mentioned yet.

Comment: Agreed. It is a good book if you want some dos and don'ts with clear examples. If you need to design user interfaces and you need to read one book, this is a good choice.

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at sitepoint's [The Principles of Beautiful Web Design](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/design1/). Also there are articles from this book [here](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/principles-beautiful-web-design).

Smashing magazine published a book and it is a good one. [take a look at it](https://shop.smashingmagazine.com/smashing-book-intl.html).

Answer (score 12):

[Designing Interfaces: Patterns for Effective Interaction Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596008031) by Jenifer Tidwell

Design patterns for user interfaces. A great reference.

Answer (score 10):

I highly recommend [Designing Interactions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262134748) by Bill Moggridge. It's an impressive (if overwhelming at first) collection of interviews, essays, examples and case studies by one of the pioneers of interaction / interface design.

Answer (score 10):

[Designing the Obvious: A Common Sense Approach to Web Application Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/032145345X) by Robert Hoekman Jr. is an excellent read.

From the back cover: 
*Designing the Obvious belongs in the toolbox of every person charged with the design and development of Web-based software, from the CEO to the programming team. Designing the Obvious explores the character traits of great Web applications and uses them as guiding principles of application design so the end result of every project instills customer satisfaction and loyalty. These principles include building only whats necessary, getting users up to speed quickly, preventing and handling errors, and designing for the activity. Designing the Obvious  does not offer a one-size-fits-all development process--in fact, it lets you use whatever process you like. Instead, it offers practical advice about how to achieve the qualities of great Web-based applications and consistently and successfully reproduce them.*

Answer (score 10):

For web sites, [Eyetracking Web Usability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321498364) might also be nice to add to the mix after the initial Krug stuff ^^

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[Information Dashboard Design: The Effective Visual Communication of Data](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596100167) by Stephen Few.

You can extend the design principles beyond dashboards per se, as they are ultimately reports and an interface to information.

Answer (score 9):

All books  Edward Tufte

Answer (score 7):

One I'm really surprised isn't here is Jesse James Garrett's, [The Elements of User Experience](http://www.jjg.net/elements/).

Also, [About Face 3](http://www.cooper.com/#about:books) – the book is good, very very detailed though.  I really wonder about their site now, tho' ;-)

Answer (score 6):

[Designing Web Interfaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596516258) is the most practical book on Interaction Design.

Answer (score 6):

Well this isn't just for UI design, however I would recommend [Designing for the Digital Age](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470229101) by Kim Goodwin (Former VP of Design at Cooper).

Alan Cooper describes it as the ultimate how-to book and I have to agree. It describes loads of methods and provides examples throughout. It goes through all the stages; research, modelling, requirements, framework, and design.

I have used it throughout my second year at university. It was great to understand the fundamentals of a usability method in class and then go to this book and be assured that every single detail would be available.

This book is huge! It is a great compliment to About Face 3 by Alan Cooper.

Answer (score 6):

- **The Humane Interface**  Revolutionary, concise, and complete.  The reason I do UX today.
- **The Psychology of Human-Computer Interaction** Arguably the book that marked usability as it's own discipline, cited by [4,362](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=The+Psychology+of+Human-Computer+Interaction&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) academic articles.  Know your classics ; )
- **The Essential Persona Lifecycle** is an awesome book, a trimmed down version of the original bible of personas *The Persona Lifecycle*.
- **The Minimal Manual** is not really a book, but the general style that came from the academic work of Carroll so fully revolutionized manuals back in the 80's it's now the de-facto standard.  However, it's exposition of how people really use documentation is something everyone should know, it will save you from making all sorts of naive assumptions when it comes to how people learn to use software and documentation!
- **Handbook of Usability Testing**  The foundational bible of UI testing.

Comment: I must look into these!

Answer (score 6):

[The Laws of Simplicity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262134721) has probably been the most important UX book in my career.  Some companies/sites don't really deal with the level of data complexity to require this kind of resource, but if you do, it's essential.

Answer (score 5):

### [Screen Design Manual:](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540439234)

**Communicating Effectively Through Multimedia**

by Frank Thissen

[image: Amazon Cover Image]

Answer (score 4):

Read this White Paper: [User Interface Analysis](http://www.uidesign.net/1999/papers/UIA1.html).

Answer (score 4):

Currently my favourite list is:

**Design in general**

- The design of everyday thinks
- About Face 2
- Made to Stick
- Humane
- Emotional design
- The inmates are running the asylum

**UI Design**

- Dont make me think
- GUI Bloopers
- Designing Interfaces

Answer (score 4):

Essential reading for anyone designing an accessible website today:

[Designing with Progressive Enhancement: Building the Web that Works for Everyone](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003CUDPA2?ie=UTF8&redirect=true&tag=thasnecobl-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=B003CUDPA2)

Answer (score 3):

My top 3:

- Don't Make Me Think (Krug)
- Effective UI (Anderson, Mcree, Wilson)
- Designing Web Interfaces (Scott & Neil)

Above all, after reading any books I would go out and do field research. Check out top sites that have a nice, fluent interface to them. Using information from the book, ask questions about usability. Do they make you think too much? Are they visually appealing as well as functional?

Pick and choose the features you like to form your own standard based on what context you're designing in. There is no black and white answer to this as it's all interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

[Tog on Interface](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201608421)
should definitely be in your must read list.

Answer (score 2):

I read all the books mentioned above and would like to add two books about cognitive psychology. Why? Because it's fundament on which UI design is based:

1. [Designing with the Mind in Mind](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/012375030X)
2. [100 things every designer needs to know about people](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321767535)

Also I think there should be some books about typographics in ui designer's must read list.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody mentioned outstanding book by Jacques Bertin - Semiology of Graphics: Diagrams, Networks, Maps. It is a really MUST READ book for any designed who works with information. Tufte took many ideas from Bertin in fact.

[image]

[http://www.amazon.com/Semiology-Graphics-Diagrams-Networks-Maps/dp/1589482611/ref=lp_B001K79076_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1335199156&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1589482611)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, surprised the Cooper Book hasn't made the list yet: [Designing for the digital age](http://www.cooper.com/journal/2009/01/designing_for_the_digital_age.html). I can't recommend it enough!

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e49820cb-954d-45ae-9cb3-1b9e8ea7fe8c), also known as the Microsoft UX guide.  Available in PDF.  (you can find in on web layout too [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx))

You don't need to read it, but it's a must reference for Windows user interface design.  It contains all thing you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

UX Basics - (Additionally which is not in the list)

Elements of User Experience - James Garett

Research based Web design and Usability Guidelines

Undercover User experience - Bowles and James Box

Designing with Mind in Mind - Jeff Johnson

Usability for the Web - Tom Brinck and others

Web Application Design Patterns  - Pawan Vora

Never miss these books, since these are RAW and PURE elementary level books.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite, and easy to read book, has got to be:

**Simple and Usable: web, mobile and interaction design**
by Giles Colborne (cxpartners)

This book is wonderful in how it covers a lot of great examples and stories on the authors experience in creating products. The way he explains his strategies to achieve simplicity is what grabbed me. The book itself has a beautiful design with photos communicating the message even stronger.

There's also a fantastic example he goes through in using 4 strategies to create simplicity by applying and showing the strategies on a tv remote control.

[image]

Some quotes from the book:

> "Simpler than a bike, until you try to ride it."
>
> "In my experience, roughly the first third of any project is spent trying to figure out what's really important. It's a nerve-wracking time, as complexity seems to spiral and there's no solution in sight. Sticking with it is the first and most important step in achieving simplicity. Don't rush into design. Understanding what's core takes time."

UX Booth did a great review on it [here](http://www.uxbooth.com/blog/a-simple-usable-book-review/)

Author's Website: http://www.simpleandusable.com/

Answer (score 0):

These are some of my personal favorites. If I have time I'll come back and mention a few more later on:

-

Interface and interaction design:

**Designing Visual Interfaces: Communication Oriented Techniques**

Dont be put off by how old it is. It has rock solid advice and extremely well organized.

**The Essential Guide to Interface Design**

Very synthetic. Great compendium of design principles, human psychological traits, design patterns, etc. Awesome reference when you need to find something fast in order to stimulate your thinking about a specific topic.

**About Face 3: The Essentials of Interaction Design**

This is THE book for design principles. I have yet to find a principle in any other book that is not present in this one. Also has very a comprehensive design pattern library with great explanations that help you think for yourself.

---

For getting "the big picture":

**Designing for the digital age**

Covers all the typical steps in a UX project with very detailed explanations on how to structure the work, how to organize the team, how to deal with stakeholders, what questions to ask, what techniques to use to find great solutiones, etc.

**Subject To Change: Creating Great Products & Services for an Uncertain World: Adaptive Path on Design**

A must-read about design strategy and culture. This will help you question company paradigms and deal with business people.

**The Elements of User Experience**

To help you understand how different disciplines can fit together / complement each other in order to create great experiences.

Answer (score 0):

[Usability Engineering](http://www.useit.com/jakob/useengbook.html) by Jakob Nielsen

This is the staple for any UX designer, I believe there is no point trying to learn a specific area of design until you digest this

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to recommend single book, we have some of most useful ones (for my crew) listed here so it might be useful for you to go through [this UX reading list](http://uxpassion.com/blog/various/user-experience-ux-reading-list)

Answer (score 0):

Next to the [GUI Bloopers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123706432) mentioned above, I would strongly recommend [Designing with the Mind in Mind](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/012375030X), written by the same author, Jeff Johnson.
This book really explains the 'why' of the rules that you can see elsewhere, with respect to how people read, recall, recognized, think, react, visualize, etc. and the related process in their brain. It may sound technical but it is definitely very easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Aza Raskin recommends [The Resonant Interface](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321375963).