# Which are the best UI related blogs/sites?

Tags: learning, resources

This goes along the lines of the [Must-read UI books](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74/must-read-user-interface-book). I haven't found too many blogs/sites that are aimed exclusively to this topic that are good resources for UI, so I hope you can recommend a few more than these.

- [Yahoo's Design Pattern Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/)
- [Welie.com's Pattern Library](http://www.welie.com/patterns/)
- [UIPatterns](http://ui-patterns.com/)
- [Jakob Nielsen on Usability and Web Design](http://www.useit.com/)

Comment: I suggest that each and every web site is posted in separate  answers.  That way we can vote for the web sites individually.

Comment: "List of..." questions that can't have one, correct (for the asker) answer aren't really what Stack Exchange is about. A certain number have been tolerated on other sites, but you should really try to avoid asking them.

Comment: ChrisF, it won't become a habit, don't worry ;)
I know this kind of questions are not always useful, but I think  compilations of books and sites/blogs are a great contribution for the Stacks.

Comment: The good blogs will be deep-linked in answers to questions and you'll eventually discover them that way. This question invites people to go off and explore the rest of the internet when they could be participating in the community that we're trying to build.

Answer (score 18):

- [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/)
- [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/)
- [Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/)

These are the three that immediately come to my mind that haven't been named already.

Comment: +1 for smashing magazine - but your list of site should be separate posts to allow each book to be evaluated separately.

Comment: I don't get why a UI blog would choose Silverlight for its *entire* website. Am I missing something?

Comment: Wow, that Quince is a UI nightmare considering it bogs the browser SO much.

Answer (score 17):

- [UX Magazine](http://www.uxmag.com/)
- [UX Booth](http://www.uxbooth.com/)
- [UX Matters](http://www.uxmatters.com/)
- [Usability Post](http://www.usabilitypost.com/)
- [Boxes and Arrows](http://www.boxesandarrows.com/)

Comment: I'm a big fan of Dmitry's Usability Post. I'm thrilled that he designed the theme for this site.

Answer (score 12):

Lukas Mathis' ignore the code:

http://ignorethecode.net/blog/

Answer (score 9):

- [Creating Passionate Users](http://headrush.typepad.com/) is far and away my favourite UI blog.
- But, let's not forget out dear leader: [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/)

Answer (score 5):

I've depended on [37signals](http://37signals.com)' [Signal vs. Noise](http://37signals.com/svn) for, what, 7 years now. One of the philosophies they've always upheld is that there's a lot to learn about design from other fields, and as such, their blog frequently goes off course and discusses anything from industrial design to architecture and cars. Each time, though, it's somehow related to design thinking. Very inspiring.

Answer (score 4):

Theresa Neil's blog: UX consultant

[theresaneil.wordpress.com](http://theresaneil.wordpress.com/)

Luke Wroblewski: Web Forms pioneer

[www.lukew.com/ff](http://www.lukew.com/ff/)

Aza Raskin's blog: UX lead on firefox

[www.azarask.in/blog](http://www.azarask.in/blog/)

Answer (score 3):

I forgot about this one:

http://uxurls.com/

It's an aggregator of numerous UX websites, including most of the ones mentionned in this thread. Some of the sites are no longer updated but it's still very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I can only post one link yet, so it would be the great [Johnny Holland Magazine](http://johnnyholland.org/).

Answer (score 1):

[UX Movement](http://uxmovement.com) is a pretty good one.

Comment: UX Movement is badly written and rarely cites any research or science to back up its claims.

Answer (score 1):

- http://konigi.com/ (all important news in UX and new tools)
- http://www.delicious.com/popular/UX (all hot articles at the moment)
- http://rosenfeldmedia.com/uxzeitgeist/
- http://52weeksofux.com/
- http://www.uxbooth.com for somewhat simplistic advices, but still useful
- http://www.uxmatters.com/ for more highbrow content, but useful
- http://www.quora.com/User-Experience - you have high chances to get detailed, deep replies from industry/startup professionals (Quora' UX designer, etc.).
- http://whitneyhess.com/blog/2009/06/30/so-you-wanna-be-a-user-experience-designer-step-1-resources/

Answer (score 1):

[Dribbble](http://dribbble.com/)

Also a big fan of Smashing Mag and UIPatterns

Answer (score 1):

- [UX Myths](http://uxmyths.com/) collects many User Experience misconceptions and explain why they are not true (based on research). It is a useful site to reference since most of these myths appear now and then in conversations.

Comment: Good one. I highly recommend this one.

Answer (score 0):

This guy has an excellent understanding of users' psychology and passion for helping them (and writing essays): [Zusch Login - Problems and Solutions in Usability and User Interface Design](http://www.zuschlogin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

We'e just started a UX and design blog called [Epic Bagel](http://www.epicbagel.com) - be fantastic if anyone has a chance to explore it a little. Started to get a small following which is great, although feedback is always welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

**Six Revisions**

**Speckboy Design magazine**

**webdesigner depot**

and many more from **Smashing Network**

Answer (score -1):

This site puts it all together quite nicely: http://www.siteownernews.com/website-usability/