# Learning about usability

Tags: resources, learning

I am very interested in user interface design and improving the user's experience. Therefore, I am thinking of moving my career in the direction of usability. I would like to try to teach myself as much as I can about usability. I've already read the classic "Don't Make Me Think" by Steve Krug, and I'm wondering what other resources are out there.

What books/ websites/ blogs/ etc. would you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

"Don't Make Me Think" is a great place to start. For further reading I suggest you take a look at [The must-read User Interface Book?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74/must-read-user-interface-book)

I would also recommend you think beyond books and blogs, and find inspiration in everyday design to drive your motivation: [Sources of UX inspiration](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5636/sources-of-ux-inspiration)

Answer (score 2):

Books that transformed my world:

- [Donald Norman's Design of Everyday
  things](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465067107): this is an introduction to ergonomics. It's a critical foundation to user experience, and a thoroughly enjoyable read.
- [Tog on Interface](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201608421) Designed for the old Mac, it's still a classic to imbue the philosophy of great GUI design (including things like [Fitt's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law) etc)
- [Tog on Software Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201489171) A follow-up to Tog on Interface
- [Jakob Nielsen's Usability Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0125184069). A great book on the process of user interface designing including user testing

For seminal articles on web page design, you must run, not walk, to [Jakob Nielsen's Alert Box columns](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/)

Answer (score 1):

As Antony have mentioned, your question has already been asked and answered.

- [Must-read User Interface Book?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74/must-read-user-interface-book)
- [Which are the best UI related blogs/sites?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/81/which-are-the-best-ui-related-blogs-sites)
- [How to become a user experience designer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/479/how-to-become-a-user-experience-designer)