# "css-tricks.com" is to "good css blog" as "_______" is to "good ui blog"

Tags: resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which are the best UI related blogs/sites?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/81/which-are-the-best-ui-related-blogs-sites)

What are some well known, industry leading blogs on UI design and best practices?

Comment: http://www.useit.com/alertbox/

Comment: You should post this as answer srcspider

Comment: similar question : http://ui.stackexchange.com/questions/81/which-are-the-best-ui-related-blogs-sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could begin with [UX Myths](http://uxmyths.com), [Little big details](http://littlebigdetails.com) and [What makes them click](http://www.whatmakesthemclick.net/articles/) for starters.

Comment: Here's another good one I found: http://www.uxbooth.com

Comment: Sounds good indeed