# Great UX blogs - any "ultimate" collection you should know of?

Tags: resources, ux-field

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which are the best UI related blogs/sites?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/81/which-are-the-best-ui-related-blogs-sites)

Where do you find inspiration for user interface design for web applications?

What are your preferred blogs and resources of inspiration?

I try to browse http://uxpad.com/ that aggregates blogs, but there's so much clutter.

Comment: I didn't know UXPad - thank you for the reference. However, I haven't yet found a news site like Engadget with a more narrow focus on (software) UI/UX news (about e.g. browsers, Mac OS X Lion, Win 8, etc.). Engadget doesn't seem to have filtering options that address such needs? I have tried to make a Yahoo Pipe with filtering of RSS feeds from e.g. Engadget, but that doesn't work well, either.

Comment: You're welcome :) I discovered UXPad just recently. Don't they have RSS feeds per tag? Maybe you could gather interesting tags, and aggregate their RSS feeds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bellow are some bookmarks

1. [Usibility Post](http://www.theuxbookmark.com/2010/08/interaction-design/a-monster-list-of-ui-guidelines-style-guides/)
2. [Yahoo Developer YPatterns](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20000319.html)
3. [Anoriod practices](http://www.theuxbookmark.com/2010/08/interaction-design/a-monster-list-of-ui-guidelines-style-guides/)
4. [Designing Help](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/23/help-elements-design-showcase/)
5. [Color Theory](http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-theory-intro.htm)
6. [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=1qyJdxba6qgC&lpg=PA90&ots=3qmQ4_94q0&dq=hiding%20anti-pattern%20bill%20scott&pg=PA91#v=onepage&q&f=false)
7. [welie.com/patterns/](http://www.welie.com/patterns/)
8. [patterntap collection](http://patterntap.com/tap/collection)
9. [Slideshare search for visual design](http://www.slideshare.net/jonfollett/visual-design-for-web-site-and-web-applications?src=related_normal&rel=1658920)
10. [Use IT](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20000319.html)

---

Visit [The UX Bookmarks](http://www.theuxbookmark.com/2010/08/interaction-design/a-monster-list-of-ui-guidelines-style-guides/) for more Bookmarks

and after all i would like to share some thing which is i think the most important aspect of inspiration

[A song to inspire confidence](http://goodexperience.com/2011/06/a-song-to-inspire-con.php)

This question is already asked.  [Which are the best UI related blogs/sites?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/81/which-are-the-best-ui-related-blogs-sites)

Answer (score 4):

a while ago I wrote an article titled "[24 inspirational blogs, books and articles on user interface patterns](http://www.paulolyslager.com/inspirational-blogs-books-articles-user-interface-patterns)". You'll probably find everything you need right there.

Comment: +1 - If I could choose two answers, I would include yours. Great article.

Answer (score 0):

This list is certainly incomplete without http://konigi.com/. Highly recommend Coopers blog as well: http://www.cooper.com/journal/

Answer (score 0):

**- [littlebigdetails.com](http://littlebigdetails.com/)** is a site I love for some quick inspiration. They showcase nice *little* features that have a *big* impact on the interface involved & that would normally be overlooked.

**[- Smashing Magazine](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/)** has a great UX section with fresh & interesting content. Always worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

[uxmyths.com](http://www.uxmyths.com) is a very useful website.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.