# What book would you recommend as a decent 'intro to UX' aimed at non-practitioners?

Tags: books

Via @uxbooks on Twitter I often get asked to recommend books on various subjects. Recently I was asked which book I would recommend to a non-practitioner as an intro to UX. I opened the question up and thought I'd do the same on here to see what people thought.

**EDIT:** Please up vote the answers you agree with so we can promote the most popular suggestions for future reference.

Comment: TO kick things off one of the responses I had was 'blueprints for the web' simple, short & introduces IA with some interaction design - http://bit.ly/O12Q3

Comment: To follow up I've taken the great feedback from this thread and turned it into a post on UXBooth for future reference. 

User Experience Books for Beginners
http://www.uxbooth.com/blog/user-experience-books-for-beginners/

Answer (score 27):

Don't make me think by Steve Krug

The best by far.  A small quick read and not too technical at all.
[Amazon Link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dont-Make-Me-Think-Usability/dp/0321344758/ref=sr%5F1%5F1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1255349814&sr=8-1)

Comment: I've made sure that every organization I've gone to has purchased multiple copies of this and had everyone involved in their websites read this.

Answer (score 14):

- The Design of Everyday Things by Donald Norman ([amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Everyday-Things-Donald-Norman/dp/0385267746))

Comment: This is a good book, but I don't necessarily find it great for non-usability people.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Answer (score 10):

A Project Guide to UX Design by Russ Unger and Carolyn Chandler is a great practical and accessible guide to what is required of ux designers, and serves as a great introduction into the field.

Answer (score 8):

Steve Krug's "Don't Make Me Think" and "Designing the Obvious" by Robert Hoekman are two good books for that intro to UX.

Answer (score 7):

I would also recommend The Humane Interface by Jef Raskin.

Comment: I would not recommend this book for non-practitioners. It contains some excellent theories about what makes a UI good or bad, but is aimed more at actual ui designers.

Answer (score 6):

Another good one that I like is [Sketching User Experiences by Bill Buxton](http://www.amazon.com/Sketching-User-Experiences-Interactive-Technologies/dp/0123740371).

Comment: Again, I don't think this is a very good starter book.  Excellent book overall, just not for beginners.

Comment: This is NOT a good book for beginners. Too abstract to offer any value for non-practitioners.

Answer (score 6):

I've already voted up Don Norman's Design of Everyday things, but his book [Emotional Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Emotional-Design-Love-Everyday-Things/dp/0465051367/ref=sr%5F1%5F1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1259325239&sr=8-1) is a great follow up with some contemporary examples. It's a quick read, but still quite insightful.

[The Inmates are Running the Asylum](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Inmates-are-Running-Asylum-High-tech/dp/0672326140/ref=sr%5F1%5F1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1259325522&sr=1-1) is another essential for understanding why we need to consider the UX.

[Interaction Design: Beyond Human Computer Interaction](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Interaction-Design-Beyond-Human-computer/dp/0470018666/ref=pd%5Fsim%5Fb%5F7) (Sharp, Rogers, Preece). While this is a textbook, it still serves as a useful reference for someone that wants a more in-depth read.

Interestingly enough, when posting the links for the above books, the 'Customers who bought this also bought...' shows most of the gems already mentioned here:

- [About Face 3](http://www.amazon.co.uk/About-Face-Essentials-Interaction-Design/dp/0470084111/ref=pd%5Fsim%5Fb%5F1) (Cooper)
- [Design of Everyday Things](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-Everyday-Things-Don-Norman/dp/0465067107/ref=pd%5Fsim%5Fb%5F2)
  (Norman)
- [Sketching User Experiences](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sketching-User-Experiences-Interactive-Technologies/dp/0123740371/ref=pd%5Fsim%5Fb%5F3)
  (Buxton)
- [The Humane Interface](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Humane-Interface-Directions-Designing-Interactive/dp/0201379376/ref=pd%5Fsim%5Fb%5F6)(Raskin)
- [Elements of User Experience](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Elements-User-Experience-User-centered-Design/dp/0735712026/ref=pd%5Fsim%5Fb%5F4)
  (Garrett)

Comment: +1 Good compilation including the inmates are running the asylum

Answer (score 5):

Kim Goodwin's Designing for the Digital Age ([amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Designing-Digital-Age-Human-Centered-Products/dp/0470229101)) is the closest thing to a UX textbook I've seen.  It presents a framework for structuring the UX design process, and then delves into the details of each step.

Answer (score 5):

About Face 3 by Alan Cooper is a very good start. It provides UX process vision, which is very important. Most other books just provide best practices and patterns.

Answer (score 5):

Just to put something new out there. [Why Software Sucks.. And what you can do about it.](http://www.amazon.com/Why-Software-Sucks-What-About/dp/0321466756)
is a great book for engineers to read... its meant to be lighthearted and poke fun at the engineers but I think it really gets it point across as to WHY UX is so important.

Answer (score 4):

This was a question I originally asked on Twitter last week that @uxbooks helpfully picked up and shared more widely, so thought it might be worth sharing what others told me direct.

Most of the responses I received are already here - with the exception of [About Face](http://www.cooper.com/insights/books/#aboutface3) By Alan Cooper, Robert Reimann & David Cronin.

Worth mentioning that Steve Krug was certainly the most popular response. Seems like it's still the starting point for most.

Answer (score 4):

Don't make me think, Krugg

Answer (score 4):

37 Signals' Defensive Design for the Web ([amazon](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/073571410X/))

Answer (score 3):

I have to agree with Matt on "Elements of User Experience" if we're talking about software/web - otherwise Dan Saffer's books or Don Norman are relatively easy reads.

Answer (score 3):

@jaysonelliot just suggested that help understand why UX exists a good book would be "[Designing for People](http://bit.ly/3xnLnb)" by Henry Dreyfuss

Answer (score 3):

I have to say apart from the obvious books that seem to get mentioned constantly I recommend reading [Web Usability Handbook](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Usability-Handbook-Internet-Mark-Pearrow/dp/1584504692/ref=sr%5F1%5F1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1255356044&sr=8-1)

Answer (score 3):

Web Design Workshop by Robin Williams is a good (but old) primer on design. Once you have that, then books on Cascading Style Sheets make a little more sense.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

- Blueprints for the web simple, (amazon [.com](http://www.amazon.com/Information-Architecture-Blueprints-Web-2nd/dp/0321600800/ref=sr%5F1%5F1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1255350032&sr=8-1) [.co.uk](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Information-Architecture-Blueprints-Web-2nd/dp/0321600800/ref=sr%5F1%5F1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1255350032&sr=8-1)) - short & introduces IA with some interaction design
- Elements of User Experience by JJG, (amazon [.com](http://www.amazon.com/Elements-User-Experience-User-centered-Design/dp/0735712026/ref=sr%5F1%5F1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1255350106&sr=1-1) [.co.uk](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Elements-User-Experience-User-centered-Design/dp/0735712026/ref=sr%5F1%5F1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1255350106&sr=1-1)) - holistic overview of what makes up user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Designing the User Interface by Ben Shneiderman and Catherine Plaisant ([amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Designing-User-Interface-Human-Computer-Interaction/dp/0321537351/)) isn't very popular but gives a nice overview of many different UX subjects. As far as I know this book is widely used by colleges and universities throughout the world.

Answer (score 2):

Don't Make Me Think was excellent!

Answer (score 2):

"Don't Make Me Think", Steve Krugg

Answer (score 2):

The Simplicity Shift, By: Scott Jenson ([amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/Simplicity-Shift-Innovative-Tactics-Corporate/dp/052152749X/ref=ntt%5Fat%5Fep%5Fdpi%5F1))

Geared toward managers, and helping them understand the process, and it's importance.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend reading **Don't Make Me Think** first, followed by **A Project Guide To UX Design**. These two books should be more than enough as a start. :)

Answer (score 2):

Communicating Design (Dan Brown) is a book I found really useful when I was starting out (in addition to Don't Make me think & A Project Guide to UX Design already mentioned above).

Communicating Design does a great job of presenting the for who, what, where, when of different kinds, and layers, of ia/ux documentation (user needs, strategy, and design documentation) that someone starting out in UX needs to understand and be able to produce.

**October 6/10 update:**

It's not a book but it's such a useful, well rounded, summary overview of UX that I thought you still might find it a useful resource:

[What Is User Experience Design? Overview, Tools And Resources](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/05/what-is-user-experience-design-overview-tools-and-resources/)

Answer (score 2):

***Understanding why Pesky Users never use Your Software the way you Designed It to be Used.***

**By Joel Spolsky****

Some of it is online here ( though obviously as it's a book its more user friendly to actually read it as a book rather than on screen )

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html

(** Actually its officially called: 'User Interface Design for Programmers', which is such a  bad title for such a good book )

When I lend my copy to people I stick a big 'Read This' post-it into this page:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html

*When you design user interfaces, it's a good idea to keep two principles in mind:
   1. Users don't have the manual, and if they did, they wouldn't read it.
   2. In fact, users can't read anything, and if they could, they wouldn't want to.*

Answer (score 1):

Chauncey Wilson's new book "User Experience Re-Mastered: Your Guide to Getting the Right Design" ([Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/User-Experience-Re-Mastered-Getting-Design/dp/0123751144/ref=sr%5F1%5F1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1256601355&sr=8-1)) could also be a good candidate. It is primarily a compilation of material from various Morgan Kaufmann books presented in a project framework.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not yet make a vote. 
so, i also suggest

> Don't make me think

it's best.

Answer (score 1):

"Designing the Obvious" and "Designing the Moment" by Robert Hoekman are both excellent starters.

They are small books. Quick and easy reads for the beginner.