# UX realted books

Tags: website-design

I know that reading UX related books doesn't make me one. but I was just curious to know what are all the UX best books are there in the market . I just want to see how a UX expert thinks . Please mention the book names .Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't a suitable question for this site I'm afraid. We're here to solve UX issues, not give out product recommendations. There are some older questions on here with book links though (which are also closed posts now, but still exist for reference) such as this one - http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4705/advanced-books-on-ux

Comment: I found this list of beginner books helpful: https://medium.com/wemake-services/books-to-get-you-started-in-ux-742e44d4c56d

Answer (score 2):

**Don't Make Me Think** by **Steve Krug** is a good one.
It has added a chapter on mobile usability as well in the third edition. It is short ,easy to read and illustrated well with examples.