# What is the difference between UX Engineer, UX Designer and Front End Developer?

Tags: ux-designer, jobs, frontend-development

I often find these designations as quite confusing and most of the companies in my country have various definition about each of the above mentioned post. I was curious what is the requirement from around the world.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UX Designer or UI Developer?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49615/ux-designer-or-ui-developer)

Comment: The constant discussion and debate around job titles is an ongoing issue as the industry/field continues to evolve. It is more important to focus on the actual task and responsibilities rather than often misleading job titles.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question, this is how I intend them:

**Front-end Developer**- the main difference can be one word: **programming**, this person can participate in the design process (visually) and develop mechanisms of action and behavior of elements (during interactions),
however the main responsibility is **transform design project to working software** (implementation process) + along with the connection to the backend.

**UX Designer**- often companies have different needs depending on the scale, the environment in which they operate and other external factors. I think that UX designer is closer to business and users, can transform business requirements into a specific solution that can be processed into 0 and 1. It can also be a researcher, scientist who collects and analyzes data to improve the existing situation.

**UX Engineer**- I may be wrong, because I do not have a mental model created for this role, but I think that he knows very well the technical details of the issue with less emphasis on business (as in the case of UX Designer. More technical - technological context than socio-business).