# What are the best UX / Interaction Design masters courses in UK or Ireland?

Tags: interaction-design, ux-field, education

Looking for the best taught masters programme in UK or Ireland in the field of User Experience / Interaction design. Ideally a 1-2 year full-time programme.

Comment: There's some overlap with a previous question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/recommended-ui-ux-ixd-master-studies

Comment: Thanks for the link PhillipW, would be interesting to find if anyone has recommendations for Irish masters courses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would actually recommend the **free online course by Standford University** [Human-Computer Interaction](http://www.hci-class.org/).

Best value for money. Evar.