# Creating a web UI for an 'Expert System'. What is the best approach?

Tags: website-design

I'm new to this site, and am finding it quite useful.
My question is that I'm creating a web-based user interface for an existing 'Expert System' ( http://bike.ballarat.edu.au/RDR.html). I'm just trying to get some ideas happening as I will be the User Experience Designer of this project, what will be the best approach to achieving this?

I can provide more details if the question is too broad.

EDIT:
 Would it be better for the above scenario to have each functionality of the system on a separate page, or have the system run on a single page?

EDIT 2:
 Let's disregard my previous questions.

The system is a knowledge expert system, which takes scenarios from users and gives answers or solutions based on the AI system implemented. Needless to say, the expert system is already up and running, but has a shocking interface (dos lines), and my team's job is to create a web-based interface to run the system on. It is a great system, and I personally don't want it being discarded or disregarded due to it not being able to be easily used. so my question is that since i'm new to the whole User Experience scene, what are some general pointers or do's and don'ts for creating such a website?
 I can also create a new question which may read "What are good pointers for a starting user-experience designer?", if that is more relevant?

Comment: Your question is definitely too broad. It lends itself more to a discussion, which sadly this site is not intended for. But if you can make a more objective question out of this (or a few), you may get some good input from the community here. Feel free to use the edit button to rewrite or clarify your question. Thanks!

Comment: Could you describe it in more detail? It's unclear what the system does, and I don't think a direct answer can be given right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this doesn't make me sound like too much of a jerk, but imagine I came over to stackoverflow and said "I don't know anything about programming, and this firm hired me as their R&D team leader - what do I need to know"?

You're talking about a complicated expert system. This category of software is very aptly named, since also in terms of UI it's complicated and should be done by experts... Some tasks are appropriate for beginners, but this is definitely not one of them.

I realize you're already in this position and you need help, but I really can't think of anything useful to tell you, apart from two things: A - try to get them to hire a good external (or, better, in-house) UI consultant that you can work with. B - [This is probably the best place to start](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74/must-read-user-interface-book), but it's a long way to go.

Sorry for being negative.

Answer (score 0):

I'd aim for something like this:

http://www.google.co.uk/

If you don't **need** a complex looking interface - don't use one.