# What's your favorite book on UX?

Tags: training

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Must-read User Interface Book?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74/must-read-user-interface-book)

Books can be on user experience, user interface, and/or usability.

Comment: Karen, please see [this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74/must-read-user-interface-book).

Comment: Also questions that just ask for a list of answers aren't particularly useful. Some do remain but only if they've generated useful answers. However, they are rare.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely Alan Cooper's [The Inmates Are Running the Asylum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672316498). It has really good examples (of bad UI/UX) from everyday life most of us can relate.

Comment: Very well written, interesting to read, and lots of good examples again and again, right from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Emotional Design by Don Norman.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say Steve Krug's "Rocket Surgery Made Easy".

Answer (score 0):

Steve Krug's Don't Make Me Think is an excellent introduction to the field.