# Awesome sources to see great UIs and usability

Tags: gui-design, usability, usability-study, tutorial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Must-read User Interface Book?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74/must-read-user-interface-book)

As an outsider (aka. not a designer) and due to the lack of time to innovate, I want to create great UIs and great usability by example, **by reading the greatest market studies and seeing the most beautiful and cutting edge UIs and usability researches.**

Please point me to such resources: sites, books, everything goes.
Help me not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I would suggest searching ux.stackexchange for 'books' and you'll find a great list of resources to get started. But to create your own great UI, the best approach is to learn from others, practice, test and ship. Then repeat.

Comment: A great place to see good UX is any Apple store.

Comment: When you say "see great UIs" are you looking for something like this: http://www.uiparade.com/ ?

Comment: In addition to what Todd said, we're happy to help you save time if you ask specific questions when a quick Google search doesn't turn up the answer. It's win-win.

Comment: @Ben Brocka: That's a nice example. Love it.

Comment: @Todd Sieling and Patrick McElhaney♦: The "Must-read User Interface Book?" question is good, but it talks too much about theory. I want to see examples! I don't consider this thread a duplicate from  the other one... But I've opened a new one. Regards.

Comment: It's not *really* a duplicate, but the question is kind of vague and I figured the books might be a good starting point. As it stands, the question isn't a good fit for the Q&A format of SE. See the FAQ.