# Book on web design with Bootstrap

Tags: resources

What book would you recommend me to read about **web design** preferably with bootstrap. I am most interested about taxonomy of different kinds of user ui and ways to arrange them in a user friendly way.

Found a related question: [The must-read User Interface Book?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74/the-must-read-user-interface-book), however I am looking for something more specific with examples and comparisons if possible.

I have chosen bootstrap in this question because it nicely breaks the ui apart into different elements. However, indeed it could be anything else with a nice taxonomy instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many in the amazon website, to learn web-design it's better to take an online courses, you could find the best courses here :

- [Udacity](http://udacity.com)- NanoDegree - Offer a great courses free and paid and if you joined their nanodegree, you will receive a certification plus a job offer. By the way, most of their instructors are working with google, so you will learn from the best.
- [Udemy](http://UDEMy.com) - There are many great free and discounted courses.

As for the book, I would highly recommend something like this ([Html&Css](http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/) design and build website).I think this is what you need, if I understood your question correctly.

Beside, Bootstrap is HTML, CSS, and JavaScript framework for developing Website and web-application. No book will teach you how to design a website/Web Application using bootstrap.However, in youtube you could find many developers/designers who will demonstrate the essential and use of bootstrap in order for you to build beautiful, clean and appealing websites/web application.

Maybe you need to elaborate more on what you are looking for. Are you interested on the visual design/User interface design or you want to learn everything from analysis of user-requirement up to the development of the application/website.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As for your question, I am a all round front- and backed designer myself. I am looking for a book with a taxonomized ui elements which will help me to create even friendlier user interfaces.

Comment: @sudo I believe you have answered ur own question " From the link you posted above - Don't make me thing". Plus, you need to look at UX/UI courses from Udacity. Another great book you may/must read is '' 100 things every designer should know" by susan. In this book, you will learn many different psychology & UCD techniques that you should apply in your design. The rest is all from your experience, whenever you design, try to test your ideas, then change the design based on your test and user-feedback - This is how you'll create a friendlier user interfaces.